# Flutter: DateTime.now() returns different values on different machines with same timezone

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I am using **DateTime.now()** to return time in local zone. This works fine. I extract timezone using **DateTime.now().timeZoneName** and it also returns correct value.

I am building a windows app for windows PC.

I run this on windows using

**flutter run -d windows**

I tried running the executable on other windows machines but the time shown is incorrect(sometimes in UTC when the timezone is not UTC). The timezone is correct.

I checked the time on other systems by running **time** command in command prompt and the time shown was the current time but **DateTime.now()** is not reflecting this.

I am not able to understand as to why is this happening. Could someone help me understand this?

Comment: When you say "sometimes in UTC", do you mean that it sometimes shows you the current UTC time with a timezone that isn't UTC?

Comment: Yes it shows time in UTC with a timezone which is not UTC. I have updated question with this detail

Comment: Are the time and time zone settings correctly set on the affected machines?  If you have a reproducible case, you perhaps should file a bug.

Comment: Yes they are and that is why I am surprised by this behavior

Comment: What does `DateTime.now().isUtc` return?

Comment: I haven't checked that. The documentation says that DateTime.now() returns local time.  But I will check that

Answer (score 0):

Other machines means with different operating systems? if Yes, don't worry the `time` and `time.zone` that is retrieved will be of the mobile device. It is irrelevant to the operating system you are using. Since app runs on mobile phones with android operating system you will get a standard output which is common for all phones.

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
 print(dateTime.timeZoneName);
 print(dateTime.timeZoneOffset);
```

**Output:**

**1. India**

```
timeZoneName: IST
timeZoneOffset: 5:30:00.000000
```

**2. America/Los_Angeles**

```
timeZoneName: PST
timeZoneOffset: -8:00:00.000000
```

timezone list: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/timezone

Also check the time in BIOS of that PC. Set it properly, if the BIOS battery is weak or not working then this problem may arise.

Comment: By other machines, I mean different PCs with windows operating system. I am building a windows app which runs on windows PC. I have updated question with this detail

Comment: Then check the time in BIOS of that PC. Set it properly, if the BIOS battery is weak or not working then this problem may arise.

Comment: The system is showing proper time. Not able to read it correctly using DateTime.Now()